# Variance of operation count in Pollard $\rho$ factorization

Tags: number-theory, statistics, prime-numbers

In TAOCP Section 4.5.4, Knuth demonstrates empirically that the average number of iterations to find a factor $p$ of $N = nq$ is roughly $2\sqrt{p}$. [Pollard](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01933667) gave a more precise estimate of the number of iterations as ${\sim}1.0308\sqrt{p}$ under the assumption that
\begin{align*}
f(x) := x^2 + b \bmod N
\end{align*}
is a random mapping.

Pollard also gives an empirical estimate of the variance of the iteration count $r(p)$ via "$r(p) < \sqrt{p}/2$ with probability 0.183" and "$r(p) > 2\sqrt{p}$ with probability 0.065".

*Can a more precise estimate of the variance be made?*

I am interested in this because the variance tells whether it's rational to attempt to restart a Pollard $\rho$ factorization if the runtime is excessive and generate a new seed.